# Unit test for angular $resource based REST is not able resolve a required dependency karma/jasmine

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner, angular-resource

I am new in jasmine/karma to write unit test cases for Angular. I have one service which uses $resource object to make server call. I tried to write test case however getting error related to not able resolve a required dependency. Following are required details.

**Application Code:**
**User.js (User resource)**

```
//create User factory
app.factory('User', ['$resource', function($resource) {
        return $resource('/users/:id', {id: '@id'}, {update: {method: 'PUT', isArray: false}});
    }]);
```

UserImplementation.js (User Service)

```
app.factory('UserImplementation', ['User', function(User) {

        var UserImplementation =
                {
                    //Get user details for given fileid
                    getUser: function(userId, getUserCallback)
                    {
                        //Create FileOperation object
                        var userObj = new User();

                        //make server call to lock the file
                        userObj.$get({id: userId}, function(response) {
                            //invoke callback
                            if (getUserCallback) {
                                getUserCallback(response);
                            }
                        });

                    },
                    //Get all user details
                    getAllUsers: function(getUsersCallback)
                    {
                        //make server call 
                        User.query(function(response) {
                            //invoke callback
                            if (getUsersCallback) {
                                getUsersCallback(response);
                            }
                        });
                    }

                };

        return UserImplementation;
    }
]);
```

**Karma/Jasmine Test code:**
**UserMock.js (ClientUnitTestData.js is having all the test data)**

```
var UserMock = {
    $get: function(userId) {
        return ClientUnitTestData.user;
    },
    query: function(userId) {
        return ClientUnitTestData.user;
    }
};
```

**UserImplementation.test.js**

```
describe('UserImplementation tests', function() {

    // Load  module.
    beforeEach(module('ThemeLibrary'));
    // Setup the mock service in an ApplicationLoaderService module.
    beforeEach(module(function($provide) {
        $provide.value('User', UserMock);
    }));

    it('Check for all required functions',
            inject(function(UserImplementation) {
                expect(angular.isFunction(UserImplementation.getUser)).toBe(true);
                expect(angular.isFunction(UserImplementation.getAllUsers)).toBe(true);
            }));

});
```

**Error:**
I am getting following error:
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.7/$injector/unpr?p0=UserImplementationProvider%20%3C-%20UserImplementation

**Edit: Updated karma config and used $httpBackend**
Following is updated UserImplementation.test.js

```
describe('UserImplementation tests', function() {
    var $httpBackend;
    // Load  module.
    beforeEach(module('ThemeLibrary'));
    // Setup the mock service in an UserImplementation module.
    beforeEach(inject(function(_$httpBackend_) {
        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
        //Get user details
        $httpBackend.expectGET('/users/' + ClientUnitTestData.user._id).respond(ClientUnitTestData.user);
        //Get all users list
        var response = [];
        $httpBackend.expectGET('/users').respond(response.push(ClientUnitTestData.user));
    }));

    it('Check for all required functions',
            inject(function(UserImplementation) {
                expect(angular.isFunction(UserImplementation.getUser)).toBe(true);
                expect(angular.isFunction(UserImplementation.getAllUsers)).toBe(true);
            }));

    it('Test getUser() function',
            inject(function(UserImplementation) {

                UserImplementation.getUser(ClientUnitTestData.user._id, function(response){
                    expect(response).toEqual(ClientUnitTestData.user);
                });



            }));

});
```

This is working fine. Is $httpBackend better approach compare to UserMock.js?

Comment: When you do `app.factory(...)` what module does `app` correspond to, "ThemeLibrary"? Is that the case for both User and UserImplementation? Have you configured karma.conf so that it can find the UserImplementation.js file? I think you need to provide some more details...

Comment: Thanks for highlighting. I missed to load these .js files in karma.conf. Now this issue is resolved. However getting new error. Going to add details.

Comment: Its working fine now. I have removed UserMock.js and now using $httpBackend.